# How to change jQuery pickadate theme

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-plugins

Hi I'm using jQuery Plugin called [pickadate.js](http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/). But I cannot get how to change the theme. There is two theme default and classic. I want to change it to classic.

Comment: 2 minutes on [the plugin's Github repository](https://github.com/amsul/pickadate.js) would have shown you [the themes folder in /v2/themes](https://github.com/amsul/pickadate.js/tree/gh-pages/v2/themes). You get a downvote for lack of effort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just include the theme CSS for the theme you want ... [Docs are here](https://github.com/amsul/pickadate.js#themes)

If you want the theme picker as shown the the plugins home page .. check [this pages source](http://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/) ...

HTML :

```
<span class="menu__link">
  Themes: 
  <input class="theme-toggle__input" type="radio" id="show_theme_default" name="show_theme" value="default" checked hidden>
  <label class="theme-toggle__label" for="show_theme_default">default</label> and 
  <input class="theme-toggle__input" type="radio" id="show_theme_classic" name="show_theme" value="classic" hidden>
  <label class="theme-toggle__label" for="show_theme_classic" class="checked-negative">classic</label>
</span>
```

JavaScript:

```
var themeSelected = window.localStorage ? localStorage.getItem( 'theme' ) : '',
    $themeLinks = $( '#theme_base, #theme_date, #theme_time' ),
    updateStylingLinks = function( value ) {
        value = value || 'default'
        $( '#show_theme_' + value ).attr( 'checked', true )
        $themeLinks.detach()
        $themeLinks.each( function() {
            this.href = this.href.replace( /(.+\/)(\w+)(.+)/, '$1' + value + '$3' )
        })
        $themeLinks.appendTo( 'head' )
    }

if ( themeSelected ) {
    updateStylingLinks( themeSelected )
}

$( '[name=show_theme]' ).on( 'change', function() {
    var value = this.value
    updateStylingLinks( value )
    if ( window.localStorage ) {
        localStorage.setItem( 'theme', value )
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

> Themes
>
> All themes are generated using LESS and compiled into the lib/themes
> folder.
>
> - One and only one base stylesheet is required. Choose a theme then include the respective pickers as well.

Answer (score 0):

My goal was to use both themes depending on if the user was on a mobile (default theme) or on the desktop (classic theme).

Without modifying their .LESS files (with is important for version upgrading), I warpped each them in different CSS namespacings like below-

```
@import "../bower_components/pickadate/lib/themes-source/_variables.less";
@import "../bower_components/pickadate/lib/themes-source/base.less";
@import "../bower_components/pickadate/lib/themes-source/base.date.less";

body.pickadate--default {
    @import "../bower_components/pickadate/lib/themes-source/default.less";
    @import "../bower_components/pickadate/lib/themes-source/default.date.less";
}
body.pickadate--classic {
    @import "../bower_components/pickadate/lib/themes-source/classic.less";
    @import "../bower_components/pickadate/lib/themes-source/classic.date.less";
}
```

Then using JavaScript, I add/remove the CSS classes to the body depending on my screen size-

```
var isDesktop = Modernizr.mq('(min-width: 768px)'); //Modernizr media queries

if (isDesktop) {
    $("body").addClass("pickadate--classic");
    $("body").removeClass("pickadate--default");
} else {
    $("body").addClass("pickadate--default");
    $("body").removeClass("pickadate--classic");
}
```

NOTE: Make sure to call your JS function on window.resize as well.